# Function is not updating Button.Text c#

Tags: c#

I have a grid of buttons that should reveal some info when they are clicked (within the button itself) For a knowledge assignment I'm trying to program minesweeper.

The grid method:

```
public void createGrid()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            grid[i] = new Cell[8];
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                chance = rand1.Next(0, 6);
                if (chance == 0 && bombAmount < 10)
                {
                    grid[i][j] = new Cell(true);
                    bombAmount++;
                }
                else
                {
                    grid[i][j] = new Cell();
                }

                grid[i][j].Name = "grid" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();
                grid[i][j].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(i * 49, j * 49);
                grid[i][j].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
                grid[i][j].TabIndex = 0;
                grid[i][j].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 26.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <8; j++)
            {
                this.Controls.Add(grid[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The Reveal method:

```
public void RevealCell(int n, int m)
    {
        if (grid[n][m].HasBomb == true)
        {
            grid[n][m].Text = "B";
        }
        else if (grid[n][m].NeighbourBombCount > 0)
        {
            grid[n][m].Text = grid[n][m].NeighbourBombCount.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            grid[n][m].Text = "NB";
        }

        grid[n][m].IsRevealed = true;
    }
```

and then there's the checking if neighbours have bombs or not method:

```
public void CheckNeighbours(int cswitch)
    {
        switch (cswitch)
        {
            // Left upper corner (i = 0, j = 0)
            case 1:
                for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0 && j == 0) { }
                        else
                        {
                            if (grid[i][j].HasBomb == true)
                            {
                                grid[0][0].NeighbourBombCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            // Upper edge (i = 0, 0 < j < 7)
            case 2:
                for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0 && j == 0) { }
                        else
                        {
                            if (grid[i][j].HasBomb == true)
                            {
                                grid[0][0].NeighbourBombCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            // Right upper corner (i = 0, j = 7)
            case 3:
                for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = -1; j <= 0; j++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0 && j == 0) { }
                        else
                        {
                            if (grid[i][j].HasBomb == true)
                            {
                                grid[0][0].NeighbourBombCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            // Right edge (0 < i < 7, j = 7)
            case 4:
                for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = -1; j <= 0; j++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0 && j == 0) { }
                        else
                        {
                            if (grid[i][j].HasBomb == true)
                            {
                                grid[0][0].NeighbourBombCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            // Right down corner (i = 7, j = 7)
            case 5:
                for (int i = -1; i <= 0; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = -1; j <= 0; j++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0 && j == 0) { }
                        else
                        {
                            if (grid[i][j].HasBomb == true)
                            {
                                grid[0][0].NeighbourBombCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            // Bottom edge (i = 7, 0 < j < 7)
            case 6:
                for (int i = -1; i <= 0; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0 && j == 0) { }
                        else
                        {
                            if (grid[i][j].HasBomb == true)
                            {
                                grid[0][0].NeighbourBombCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            // Left down corner (i = 7, j = 0)
            case 7:
                for (int i = -1; i <= 0; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0 && j == 0) { }
                        else
                        {
                            if (grid[i][j].HasBomb == true)
                            {
                                grid[0][0].NeighbourBombCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            // Left edge (i = 0, 0 < j < 7)
            case 8:
                for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0 && j == 0) { }
                        else
                        {
                            if (grid[i][j].HasBomb == true)
                            {
                                grid[0][0].NeighbourBombCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            default:
                for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0 && j == 0) { }
                        else
                        {
                            if (grid[i][j].HasBomb == true)
                            {
                                grid[0][0].NeighbourBombCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

        }
    }
```

As my buttons are laid out in grid fashion the Top left button is button 1 and right bottom button is button 64 (hence the switch statements).

Edit: Didn't add the Click method to the `grid[i][j].Click += handler`...
Update:

```
        private void Cell_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        e.
        if(i == 0 && j == 0)
        {
            CheckNeighbours(1);
        }

        if (i == 0 && j > 0 && j < 7)
        {
            CheckNeighbours(2);
        }

        if (i == 0 && j == 7)
        {
            CheckNeighbours(3);
        }

        if (i > 0 && i < 7 && j == 7)
        {
            CheckNeighbours(4);
        }

        if (i == 7 && j == 7)
        {
            CheckNeighbours(5);
        }

        if (i == 7 && j > 0 && j < 7)
        {
            CheckNeighbours(6);
        }

        if (i == 7 && j == 0)
        {
            CheckNeighbours(7);
        }

        if(i > 0 && i < 7 && j == 0)
        {
            CheckNeighbours(8);
        }

        RevealCell(i, j);

    }
```

Now I just need to know how to grab the i and j indeces from the sender object and I'm golden!

Comment: Does `Cell1_Click` etc ever get called?  If you set a breakpoint there in debug mode?  I don't see anywhere that you're hooking up your events to the event handlers.

Comment: I am daft.... I never assign the click event to the custom functions. Your comment put me on the right track I guess, now to figure out how to make `grid[i][j]` assign to `Cellx_Click`

Comment: You probably want only one event handler, and a custom EventArgs that contains the coordinates.  That way you can just assign it in your initialization.  From there you should be able to calculate the values to pass to CheckNeighbors and RevealCell. (The latter being self-evident).

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, Could you explain further perhaps? that would immediately solve the super lengthy code file I got right now!

Comment: feels like we are going to watch you write your minesweeper game in a series of questions. Sadly we will never see it finished (you wont ask a question when it works). You just need to add a single onclick handler to the cells , the eventargts will have the cell object in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need

```
cell[i][j].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.CellClick);
```

and create a single CellClick event handler method

Comment: Well that won't work.  It needs to be a lambda in order to use i,j.  so `cell[i][j].Click += (sender, eventArgs) => { CellClick(i, j); };` or something like that.

Comment: This looks promising, I will post you a link to github to the finished application whenever I get around to it pm100.

Comment: @DaxFohl Nope brain = fried... I can't figure out how to access the i and j parts with 1 eventhandler

Comment: @pm100 as stated the github link for the "completed" application. There's a todo list however because some bugs are still in the application:

`1. The check for neighbouring cells isn't optimized and will throw an error for the topmost row entirely`
`2. The neighbouring cells aren't displaying the neighbouring bombs properly at least in the center of the screen, somehow only the edge cases are working as they should`

[link](https://github.com/tarqs/MSweeper/tree/master)